# Entity Framework - 3 tables have relationships with each other

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have 3 tables as follows:

**ApplicationUser:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ..some basic properties..

    // navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

**Post**:

```
public class Post
{
        public long Id { get; set; }    
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int? AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

**Album**:

```
public class Album
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and finally **ApplicationDbContext**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(a=>a.Posts)
                .WithRequired(a=>a.User)
                .HasForeignKey(a=>a.UserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                .HasKey(a => a.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u=>u.Albums)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(a=>a.UserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                .HasMany(a=>a.Posts)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(p=>p.AlbumId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

When I run the migration and update database, I get an error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Posts_dbo.Albums_AlbumId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "aspnet-Link-20161012104217", table "dbo.Albums", column 'Id'.

Could anyone tell my why they conflict? It seems pretty legit to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you set `AlbumId` as `nullable` but in configuration defined `WithRequeired()`:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }    
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int? AlbumId { get; set; }       //<-- this one
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
            .HasMany(a=>a.Posts)
            .WithRequired() //<-- this one
            .HasForeignKey(p=>p.AlbumId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

If `AlbumId` is `nullable` you should change the configuration:

```
//Ef by default conventions set the AlbumId as foreign key
modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
            .HasMany(a=>a.Posts)
            .WithOptional(a=>a.Album);
```

and if `AlbumId` isn't `nullable` change the property:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }    
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int AlbumId { get; set; }     
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

and use following configuration:

```
//Ef by default conventions set the AlbumId as foreign key
modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
            .HasMany(a=>a.Posts)
            .WithRequired(a=>a.Album)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: this is NOT the problem. the modelbuilder will always override the FK type. The problem is that the FK constraint is violated, so there is some post without an album (or a not existant one).

Comment: it works, thank you very much, I thought "WithRequired" meant each album must have blogs, turns out it's opposite